# Codeigniter and Jquery Mobile the right way of submitting a form

Tags: jquery, forms, codeigniter, mobile

I'm creating a website using jquery mobile and codeigniter. I'm still a jquery mobile newbie and have difficulty on submitting a form. I have a form like below:

```
<form action="<?=base_url().index_page()?>main/register" method="post">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="txtEmail" id="labelEmail">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" value="" data-mini="true" />
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="submit" name="btnRegister" value="Register Now" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is, instead of going to register function in main.php, I had an error box saying "Error loading page". What is the proper way to submit this form anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if the problem has been solved or not, but try to add the following attribute to your form element

```
data-ajax="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember having a similar problem.  I think its because when the form is submitted it tries to make an AJAX call.  Try adding this to the page and see if it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind('mobileinit', function ()
    {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    });
</script>
```